# uiautomatorviewer - does not show WebView content when using Emulator

Tags: android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

When I use uiautomatorviewer to dump some structure on Emulator the last element showed is android.webkit.WebView. This is actually different than real device where i have no problems detecting objects on native view. Since i am automating tests with appium this may be a problem and will force to change context. Device API = 22(Android 5.1)

Is this fault in uiautomatorviewer or some settings can be applied?

Comment: That solved my problem:
Settings -> Accessibility -> ClockBack -> ON

Comment: So unfortunately problem is not solved entirely, still i cannot see some IDs and content-descryptions